# How to upload multiple images to Ubercart product pages via FTP?

Tags: 7, media, ubercart

I have a few thousand products that I plan to upload to a D7/Ubercart website and each one will have two or three images associated with it. Is there a way I can just dump all of those images onto the server and have them somehow be associated with their correct products? Or am I stuck uploading each one individually via the node edit fields?

Thanks!

Comment: Use feeds (drupal.org/project/feeds), create custom target to reach required effect

Comment: i think it is not possible, instead you can search for multiple image upload for a product.

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it in similar, but not exact circumstances, was to use [Node export module](https://drupal.org/project/node_export). It has it's import option. On an import, it expects images to be already uploaded, so the steps are:

- Create two products with couple of images manually
- See where it's images went
- Upload the rest of your images in the same place
- Export your products to a file format you are comfortable with, like CSV / DSV
- Add the rest of your products to that file, using your manually added ones as examples
- Import products from file

My nodes weren't Ubercart products, but above procedure should work none the less.

Remember: Files uploaded will not be managed until and unless you import nodes to use them, so it's a good idea to turn off any "garbage cleaning" modules you may have to avoid their deletion.

Comment: That's an interesting method. I will give it a shot and will report back here with the results. Thanks!